# Swift 3 URL Session - add time out against URL

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession, swift3

The following code is working great but I need to add a timeout if data connection is too slow.

```
  func preload(){

        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/loadteams.php")
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)

        if data == nil{
                 showAlert()

            }else{
        values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [[String : AnyObject]]

        }

       }
```

I assume I need to bring URLSession into this but I am not sure how to do so, I understand it should be something along the lines.

```
 let urlconfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        urlconfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5
        urlconfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 5
        self.session = URLSession(configuration: urlconfig, delegate: self.delegates, delegateQueue: nil)
```

This has error no delegates

Comment: What about to use networking framework, like Alamofire. It is robust and usable library that solves all the possibilities and ways. This could lead to many errors when applied in different networking situations.

Comment: I really don't want to use any frameworks at the moment if I can help it.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `dataTask(with:)`:

```
let session: URLSession = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 5
    return URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
}()

func preload(completionHandler: @escaping ([[String: AnyObject]]?) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/loadteams.php")!

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data, let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []), let array = json as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completionHandler(array)
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completionHandler(nil)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

You may have noticed, though, that unlike your rendition, this is asynchronous. So you probably should apply a completion handler pattern, so you know when it's done. So, I'd personally do the UI update from the caller, e.g.:

```
preload() { values in
    guard let values = values else {
        self.showAlert()
        return
    }

    self.values = values
    // trigger whatever UI update you want here
}
```

Comment: adamprocter, please politely provide full warning and the line that is problematic.

Comment: @Rob Ah thanks sorry I forget to put in latest code as well for Swift 3 changes as I am not using NSArrary now... values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [[String : AnyObject]]

Comment: so what should line   func preload(completionHandler: @escaping (NSArray) -> Void) {    be ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. That `func preload(...) {...}` is the declaration of the function, so you put that anywhere in your class (e.g. if calling it from your `ViewController` class, you might have that method in your view controller). Regarding where you do the `preload() { ... }` call, as shown at the end of the answer, well, you just do that wherever you're calling this from (e.g. maybe you call this from your `viewDidLoad` or whatever).

Comment: @Rob thanks for updating the code above let me try the changes and get back to you. Apologies if I made it slightly confused.

Comment: How do you know if the request timed out? Does it call the completionHandler with an error?

Comment: @Jason - Yes it does.